# neutral Tannakian categories

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the following Corollary in [Deligne and Milne's Tannakian Categories](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.pdf). I don't know which obvious thing I'm missing, but why is the last sentence "Obviously $F \mapsto F^*$ and $f \mapsto \omega^f$ are inverse maps" true? Maybe someone who has read the book could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment, but I'm not permitted to comment. I think all that is meant is that when you form the two composites, you "obviously" get the identity map.